# How to get selected items with Chosen JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using chosen for my multiple select box, but I don't know how to get the selected items?

```
  <select class="multiselect" multiple="" name="parlementId">           
        @foreach (Politicus p in politici)
        { 
            <option value="@p.politicusID">@Html.DisplayName(p.Account.voornaam.ToString())</option>
        }

  </select>
```

```
  $('.multiselect').chosen({ width: '500px', allow_single_deselect: true, max_selected_options: 5 });

  $('.multiselect').on('change', function (evt, params) {
       //this is where I need to know which options are selected
  });
```

Comment: jquery chosen places selected values in a hidden field what i remember in a comma delimited stirng

Comment: you just need to access that hidden field value

Comment: I can't find those hidden field in my source code wehn I selected a list value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get like this:

```
var values = $(".multiselect").chosen().val();
// this will give you values in an array
```

See [**Documentation here**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)

or:

```
 var values = $(".multiselect").val();
```

Comment: for some reason, I had to use var values = $(".multiselect").val();, using chosen() between it caused my selectlist to behave in a weird way and did not return any value

Comment: yes logicallly ``$(".multiselect").val();`` should also return the selected vals,but i have not tired it...

Comment: i add that one also in the answer so it will help others having same problem.